# Is AnonymousPipeStream an appropriate choice for passing data between Tasks in the same Process

Tags: c#, multithreading, pipe, memorystream

I have a process that may spawn concurrent `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` items.

To simplify the description, I have one **master** task, and other **child** tasks.

---

SubTask **A** - This receives an incoming-flow of data (an incoming stream of bytes) from the **master** task.

- For this item, I have used an `AnonymousPipeStream` (created by the **master**, and then the client-pipe-handle passed to the **child** task on creation)

---

SubTask **B** (in progress) is different - This needs to have bi-directional data-flow with the **master**.

- I thought of using `AnonymousPipeStream` again, but this only allows one-way data-flow.
- I also considered `MemoryStream`, but this does not allow blocking (e.g. a `Read()` call within the sub-task to block until there is enough data available for it from the parent)
- A `NamedPipe` seems possible (two-way communication), but seems overkill given that the communication is within the same process and does not need to be externally-visible.

---

Finally, I considered creating a `TwoWayAnonymousPipe` class (by inheriting from `PipeStream`, and using two one-way `AnonymousPipeStream` items under the hood)

Something that exposes a `Stream` object would be useful, given that the subtask calls an API ( `System.Net.Security.SslStream().AuthenticateAsClient()` ) that expects to be handed a `Stream`.

**Question:** Does this seem a "suitable" approach to solving the problem, or have I overlooked a 'better' existing solution ?

> *Note*: I appreciate that "better" has multiple interpretations -- I am hoping for "clarity, stability, well-supported and documented", not necessarily "fastest"

---

### UPDATE (to description of task)

To enhance the explanation a bit:

- The **master** tasks deals with the `NetworkStream` ( packet-based items with a header+payload )
- some of the network data may include an SSL/TLS flow (spread over multiple packets/fragments)
- The **child(A)** is mainly a logger/decoder, and **child(B)** is mostly a wrapper for `System.Net.Security.SslStream` that handles the decoding of the inner payload-stream and handshake (which might be spread over multiple packets)
- `System.Net.Security.SslStream` has an *AuthenticateAsClient* method which requires a two-way `Stream`
- Neither task needs direct-access to the parent stream
- The **child**'s `Task` is intended to allow the encryption-task to run "separately" from the main `NetworkStream`-handling task.
- One of the main reasons I considered `PipeStream` over `MemoryStream` was due to the inbuilt ability to handle blocking `Read()` if we have not yet received enough fragments from the **master** to form a full SSL-packet.

Hence, (whilst I appreciate the benefits of the TPL-Dataflow), I'm not yet convinced it is ideal for this particular case ... the main "aim" is to wrap a byte-stream into a blockable two-way `Stream` (and yet allow the encryption-item to be offloaded and run in the background) ...

### UPDATE (Research in progress):

Current research items (thanks to feedback provided)

- [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Task Parallel Library (TPL -- Dataflow)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)
- Helpful reference document found: [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming **Async/Await**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: I do not understand why you need to use a `pipe` to make internal communication inside one app domain. Please take a look at TPL Data-flow. It's based on know patterns inside .NET framework and if you need even more complex compositions, you can combine them with Rx (Reactive Framework).

Comment: Mainly because the "data" already comes from a `NetworkStream` and hence a `PipeStream` seemed a sensible approach to offload the feed for processing.

Comment: Hence, if you are referring to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx , this seems to focus more on "message-passing", rather than simpler byte-streams ... It is likely that the **child** task will just be handling a small section of the logic (SSLStream inside a data-wrapper) but I will certainly look into it (even though it doesn't yet appear to be part of the base Framework)

Comment: You are right, when we are composing streams in a non-concurrent manner. But (IMHO) it seems when you go async and have multiple child `Task`/Agents, you have to somehow manage multiplexing, making chunks, throttling and things and even `*Async` methods can not help directly. But TPL Dataflow provides that in a clean design.

Comment: Thanks - I'll certainly look into it.... -- Fortunately I don't need multiplexing / throttling / chunking... But, It is possible I might still be going about this the wrong way and that introducing the sub-task is just complicating things unnecessarily - I'm trying to wrap some `SslStream` authentication (against specific payload-data received by the **parent** task). I certainly agree that `Async` methods might solve help with some problems, they don't always "*solve"* the problem, they just highlight the next level of complexity to be dealt with

Comment: Another abstraction you can work with is ReactiveExtensions, however in this case I would suspect TPL-DS is the solution you want.

Comment: Are you trying to duplicate the incoming stream and make it available for both "subtasks" to pull data from? And only B needs to write to the stream?

Comment: @Aron - I'll look into it, but I also suspect that TPL-dataflow (or Streams) may still be the most appropriate ...

Comment: @usr - No, neither subtask needs access to the master-stream (question extended to provide more description)